# Transform Array of Objects to spesific Object structure Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```html
[
   {
      "Hari Libur":{
         "date":"12-07"
      }
   },
   {
      "Hari Libur":{
         "date":"12-12"
      }
   },
   {
      "Hari Libur":{
         "date":"12-04"
    }
]
```

Into this Object structure

```html
{
    'Hari Libur': {date: '12/07'},
    'Hari Libur': {date: '12/12'},
    'Hari Libur': {date: '12/04'}
}
```

I have tried with Object.assign but it also include me with 0:{} , 1:{}, 2:{}.

Is there any other way to do ?

Comment: You can't create an object like that as it can't have duplicate keys

Comment: I’m not sure you can have the same key more than once.  Why not just add a dates array to the key?

Comment: So Its possible with unique keys ? mine is just an example , the point is can I achieve second structure from the first data ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr =[
   {
      "Hari Libur":{
         "date":"12-07"
      }
   },
   {
      "Hari Libur1":{
         "date":"12-12"
      }
   },
];
var obj ={}
var res = arr.map(d=>{
  var key = Reflect.ownKeys(d);
  var date = d[key].date;
  obj[key[0]]={"date":date}
})
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: This will help you get your specified structure

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).